# How to implicate IFERROR into this function in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I add the `IFERROR()` statement into this:

```
=IF(B14-C14>0,B14-C14,"")
```

Comment: Try `=IFERROR(IF(B14-C14>0,B14-C14,""),"Your Message Here")`.

Comment: What cell are you using this formula in?

Comment: What about =IF(iferror(B14-C14>0,0),B14-C14,"")

Answer (score 1):

Take entire **`EXPR`** (without primary equals sign `'='`) and simply re-write as follows:

```
= IFERROR(EXPR,"Fun=Smile.Learn=Fun.( ▀ ͜͞ʖ▀)=Ε/̵͇̿̿/’̿’̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ")
```

Now. In your case we have:
**`EXPR`** = `IF(B14-C14>0,B14-C14,"")`, substituting into above yields:

```
= IFERROR(IF(B14-C14>0,B14-C14),"Fun=Smile.Learn=Fun.(▀ ͜͞ʖ▀)=Ε/̵͇̿̿/’̿’̿ ̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ̿̿ ")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function, called `IsError()`, which you can use in an `IF()` function, as follows:

```
=If(IsError(try_expression(...)), value_if_error, value_is_no_error)
```

So your formula would become something like:

```
=If(IsError(B14-C14), "Error", If(B14-C14>0, B14-C14, "empty"))
```

This gives following results:

- `Error` in case the subtraction between `B14` and `C14` fails.
- `empty` in case the subtraction between `B14` and `C14` works but yields a negative number.
- `B14` - `C14` in all other cases.

Good luck